# Batch File using sed in windows - unexpected append instead of replace

Tags: batch-file, sed, gnuwin32

I've been tasked with migrating a group of batch scripts to Windows 7 (from XP) and have had a few problems using sed for substitution. What i need the line to do is find LogPath and anything inside the double quotes should be replaced with ABC (just for testing - will actually be a UNC path).

However instead I'm getting two strange problems:

- it's deleting the first double quote
- more importantly it isn't
  actually replacing anything inside the quotes, but instead is just
  appending to this string

Here is the relevant line of the script:

`sed \\fs-bri-01\9732\9732.hfls -i -e s,LogPath="*.",LogPath="ABC",g`

This script works on Windows XP but not Windows 7.

Comment: are you sure of the `*.` part? Isn't it `.*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well figured a work around posting it below for anyone stuck in the same situation.

```
sed \\fs-bri-01\9732\9732.hfls -i -e "s/LogPath=\"[\:A-Z0-9a-z_\\\/\.\ ]*\"/LogPath=\"ABC\"/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem comes from the UNC path:

```
pushd \\fs-bri-01\9732
sed 9732.fls -i -e s,LogPath="*.",LogPath="ABC",g
popd
```

But maybe the problem comes from the quote characters and the way sed gets its argv array. Then you can try:

```
sed -i -e "s/LogPath=\".*\"/LogPath=\"ABC\"/g" \\fs-bri-01\9732\9732.hfls
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be the UNC path due to the script actually editing the file just not how i want it. The quotes are a standard part of regex which are used to find anything inside the quote marks so wouldn't think it would be that but can't be sure. Well i would try to use a sed script file if i knew what extension that is :D. But really trying to avoid having this in a seperate file as this script already has 5/6 script files related to it.

Comment: Ahhh escape characters that's what i was missing :P. Lol mind u doesn't exactly work instead it does replace what's inside the double quotes but also removes everything else off the line :P. Is it me or is it acting a little loopy ?

Comment: @user914244: sed is greedy. So `.*"` will match everything until the LAST double quote. If you want non-greedy matching then use Perl for example: `perl -pe "s/LogPath=\".*?\"/LogPath=\"ABC\"/g;"`

Comment: No way i can do non-greedy in a batch script ?

Comment: Well figured a work around posting it below for anyone stuck in the same situation.                                                     sed \\fs-bri-01\9732\9732.hfls -i -e "s/LogPath=\"[\:A-Z0-9a-z\_\\\/\.\ ]*\"/LogPath=\"ABC\"/g"